# Error: Failed to generate emma coverage. Is emma jar on classpath? while generating code coverage report

Tags: android, emma

I am getting

> Error: Failed to generate emma coverage. Is emma jar on classpath?

while generation coverage report for android test project  i am using `adb shell am instrument -w -e coverage true com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner` command for run the test and get the coverage any idea what would be the fix for this.

Comment: Code coverage is working on my application's androidTests, but I'm getting on this error from a library module's androidTests =(

Answer (score -1):

Its because you apk and instrumented code is not EMMA-instrumented.